# Include current branch in git alias

Tags: git

I have a simple git alias:

`shipit = push origin master`

Is there any way to detect the current branch?

For example: push origin 'currentbranch'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use `HEAD` to reference the current branch.

```
shipit = push origin HEAD
```

Answer (score 1):

There might not *be* a current branch ("detached HEAD" mode, where `HEAD` contains a raw SHA-1 instead of a branch name).

If there *is* a current branch, it is stored as a symbolic reference in `HEAD`:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
refs/heads/master
$ git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
master
```

If `HEAD` is detached:

```
$ git symbolic-ref HEAD
fatal: ref HEAD is not a symbolic ref
```

For the particular case of pushing, as [Derek S already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29755548/1256452), you can just use the name `HEAD` directly.  (This works for some other commands too; for those where it's not available, use `git symbolic-ref`.)